# np.where for finding differences, nans mixed with not nan values

Tags: python, numpy

If I compare two array which contain `NaNs` like so:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [np.nan, 2, 3]])
b = np.array([[1,2,3], [np.nan, 2, 3]])
np.where(a==b, a, -1)
```

I get

```
 array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [-1.,  2.,  3.]])
```

which makes sense because:

```
np.nan == np.nan
```

yields `False`

However, `np.where(a is b, a, -1)` does not make sense either.

```
np.allclose(a, b, 1e-5)
```

yields `False`

Since bith arrays have the same values, how can I prove that?

Comment: Also, relevant - numpy.testing.assert_almost_equal.

Comment: When trying understand this `where`, make sure you understand the first, condition argument (by itself).  `a==b` and `a is b` test two very different things.